# How to send and read json data between two mvc sites

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I want to send some encrypted json data from one ASP.NET MVC site to another, via the client accessing the site.

For example, a client clicks a link on site A, which then creates a unique Json object containing, perhaps, something like this:

```
var auth = { "name" : "John", "age" : "20", "data" : "abc" };
```

I want site B to be able to retrieve, decrypt, and read the data.

What I'm lost with, is I don't know how to send the data between the two sites. I've done lots of research into POST/GET, and none of what I've seen has been very clear with something as simple as sending a single json object between two sites.

So what I'm asking is two things, is there an easier way to go about this and does this seem like sound logic? And if you have any references or examples that I can use to better understand how to send data between sites, that'd also be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'send to another site'? If I'm understanding your question correclty, this is relatively simple. All you'd need to do is have some javascript on site A, to send an ajax request to a controller on site B.

Comment: I have two ASP.NET MVC applications, and when a user clicks a link site A, it redirects them to site B. I want site A to create an encrypted json file when it redirects, that site B can access and read. The json will basically just verify that the user came from site A. Site B would then just create a cookie with some arbitrary expiration date so the user doesn't need to go between sites to be verified again. If you think ajax can do that, can you show me a simple example or resource to do that?

Answer (score 0):

sending data between two different sites is not as mushy as you think okay firstly if you are in development environment i.e., Visual Studio then you need to run both sites in two different insistences of visual studios by this you get  addresses like

site a: localhost:5005/
site b: localhost:6012/

now if you are posting from site a to site b then your url will be like

localhost:6012/Home/Index.....

ie

```
$.post("localhost:6012/Home/Index",{auth:auth},successFunction);
```

Comment: Okay, so you're using jQuery to send the data {auth:auth} from site A to site B? Can you show me how site B would interpret this data? Also, is there a way to make the post call from inside an action of a controller in site A? And make the interpretation of the data in site B from an action in a controller of site B? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can redirect from the controller side but then you will be on the view of that site ie site a to b then siteb actions view i think you should be looking at Web API instead of two sites and then make the two sites share the API